# Mouse movement events in NCurses

Tags: c, linux, terminal, mouseevent, ncurses

I wonder if there is such a thing as mouse movement events in NCurses, and if there is a way to catch them. Following the [Interfacing with the mouse](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/mouse.html) (from the [NCurses programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)) it seems that by enabling the `REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION` bit in the call to `mousemask`, one can indeed catch mouse movement events.

So, I tried that and it does not seem to work. I have something like this:

```
int ch, count=0;
mmask_t old;

initscr ();
noecho ();
cbreak ();
mousemask (ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS | REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION, &old);
keypad (stdscr, TRUE);

while ((ch = getchar ()) != 'q')
{
  count++;
  if (ch == KEY_MOUSE)
  {
     MEVENT event;
     assert (getmouse (&event) == OK);
     mvprintw (0, 0, "Mouse Event!\n");
  }
  mvprintw (1, 1, "Event number %4d",count);
}

...
```

I expected that as I'll move my mouse cursor, I'll see the event counter increasing. But it didn't. I also tried moving it while mouse button 1 is down to see if generates "drag" events, and it also didn't do anything. The question is, if it's simply a problem of my terminal emulator? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what NCurses considers as mouse movement events? All the other mouse events were received (and I can operate programs in the console that use the mouse).

I tried gnome-terminal, xterm, and some other stuff. I also tried a textual environment (without X) by going to the tty's of my linux machine (Fedora 15, Ctrl+Alt+F2) and that did not work.

Finally, assuming I do get this right and those events should be reported, what is the `bstate` field of a `MEVENT` for a mouse movement evenet?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need:

1. a terminal which supports mouse event reporting;
2. `$TERM` pointing to a terminfo entry which has an appropriate `XM` entry to initialise the terminal correctly.

`xterm` at least satisfies (1); for (2), it's likely that you'll need to set a different value for `TERM`.

Try:

- `TERM=xterm-1002` to get a position event when the cursor moves to a different cell while a button is being held down; or
- `TERM=xterm-1003` to always get a position event whenever the cursor moves to a different cell, even if no button is pressed.

The resulting events have the `REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION` bit set on the `bstate` field.

(The "PORTABILITY" section of the [`curs_mouse(3x)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_mouse.3x.html) man page describes the terminal initialisation, and the "Mouse Tracking" section of the [Xterm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) documentation describes the relevant "private mode" extensions.)

The code that you've given above needs to use `getch()`, not `getchar()`; and needs a `refresh()` inside the loop!  Other than that, it works for me with `xterm` when using one of the appropriate `TERM` settings.

Comment: I typed getchar in stackoverflow accidently, my real code did use getch. I skipped the refresh again when I typed the pseudo code here :P Anyways, many thanks - your suggestion with xterm worked very well!

Comment: Is there any way to make a program set that `TERM` variable for itself? I know you can start a program with it set by doing `TERM=xterm-1002 ./program`, for example, but is there any way to either somehow set it as the program's child process is created from the code, or have the program fork/start a new process of itself with the variable set?