# Is it possible to change the mouse icon from a terminal app?

Tags: c, ncurses

Title pretty much says it all:  I'm wondering whether it's possible to change the mouse cursor icon in response to feedback in a terminal app (e.g., a click event) from the ncurses library or another library?

For example:  I am running xterm under X, and a curses application inside that xterm.  I may or may not be sshed into another box.

A user clicks on an element of my cursor app -- is it possible to change the mouse cursor icon from a bar to a plus sign in response to the click?

There is some information here but I'd like a more complete resource:

[Mouse movement events in NCurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462850/mouse-movement-events-in-ncurses?rq=1)

Comment: You should start a new thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "mouse icon" in the context of a Terminal?

Comment: Not a terminal exclusively (not a vt), but rather at terminal running in a windowed environment.  Some applications (e.g., tmux) provide limited mouse support when running in a window environment, I'm wondering how that's done and what are the limits of the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is. ncurses can [read events from the mouse](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_mouse.3x.html) but not actually change mouse cursor settings. The terminal sends mouse movement and clicks to the ncurses program as [escape sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#Mouse%20Tracking).

Some terminals, such as putty, will change the cursor to an arrow when a region is clickable. Otherwise, a text selection cursor is shown. But I don't think this is controllable through escape sequences.