# Continually track mouse coordinates

Tags: ruby, curses

I want to continually track the mouse as it moves, or at least every 0.5 seconds:

```
require "curses"
include Curses



init_screen
start_color
init_pair(COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_WHITE)
init_pair(COLOR_RED,COLOR_RED,COLOR_WHITE)
crmode
noecho
stdscr.keypad(true)

close = false

begin
  mousemask(BUTTON1_CLICKED|BUTTON2_CLICKED|BUTTON3_CLICKED|BUTTON4_CLICKED)

  count = 0

  while( count < 10 )

        sleep 0.5

          m = getmouse


          winx = Window.new(7,30,10,10)
          winx.keypad = true
          winx.box(?|, ?-, ?+)
          winx.setpos(2,3)
          winx.addstr "Loop Count: " + count.to_s
          winx.setpos(3,3)
          winx.addstr "Mouse Position: " + m.inspect



          winx.refresh


          count += 1
  end


refresh
ensure
    close_screen
end
```

I think I'm close, but for some reason, getmouse is returning nill? Why is this? Does getmouse only work after an event such as a click? If so, is it impossible to continually track the mouse?

This from the [ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html)

> getmouse() click to toggle source
>
> Returns coordinates of the mouse.
>
> This will read and pop the mouse event data off the queue
>
> See the BUTTON*, ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS and REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION constants

`REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION` appears to be key here, but I really don't know how to use these constants. `getmouse(REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION)` doesn't work..sorry if that's majorly nooby, but there isn't much documentation out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION` to your `mousemask`:

```
mousemask(BUTTON1_CLICKED|BUTTON2_CLICKED|BUTTON3_CLICKED|BUTTON4_CLICKED|REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION)
```

Or perhaps just

```
mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS)
```

Curses processes mouse clicks in the same stream as key presses. So you need to get your mouse events with `getch`.

In your case, I recommend setting `getch` to non-blocking read `stdscr.timeout=0` and adding a case statement:

```
case getch
when KEY_MOUSE
  m = getmouse
  winx.addstr "Mouse Position: #{m.x} #{m.y} #{m.z}"
end
```

Unfortunately on my system this only reports mouse movement when I click, so you might be out of luck depending on your curses implementation/terminal.

If you aren't too afraid of C, I recommend reading the ncurses C documentation. Ruby's curses library is basically a direct translation of it.

Comment: Ah that's a real shame about only reporting on a click. Any ideas on any work around at all? It's not crucial, just wanted to spice up my application a little bit with hover effects :)

Comment: I can't think of any way to work around this. You might be able to read up on which terminals support mouse movement and only target those.

Comment: Yes, okay :). Using the code in my example and testing for nil would a good test to see if the terminal supports mouse movement I think.

Answer (score 1):

According to the TLDP nurses documentation, you need to use REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION Asa constant in your mouse mask. Try this:

```
mousemask(REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION|BUTTON1_CLICKED|BUTTON2_CLICKED|BUTTON3_CLICKED|BUTTON4_CLICKED)
```

This tells curses to report the mouse position as an event.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [Mouse movement events in NCurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462850/mouse-movement-events-in-ncurses).

Mouse event reporting depends heavily on the terminal emulator (on a Mac in iTerm2, I had to "Enable xterm mouse reporting" in preferences), and on the TERM settings as described above (I had to launch ruby like `TERM=xterm-1003 ruby curses_mouse.rb`)

Also, you must call `getch` and test for `KEY_MOUSE` before calling `getmouse`.  For example, if you're only interested in mouse events:

```
c = getch
case c
when KEY_MOUSE
  m = getmouse
end
```

Also, add `|REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION` to `mousemask` call.