# ncurses only reporting mouse movement when bstate is non-zero

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm following along with the code from

https://gist.github.com/sylt/93d3f7b77e7f3a881603

Here it is, in case of 404

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();

  // Enables keypad mode. This makes (at least for me) mouse events getting
  // reported as KEY_MOUSE, instead as of random letters.
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

  // Don't mask any mouse events
  mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS | REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION, NULL);

  printf("\033[?1003h\n"); // Makes the terminal report mouse movement events
  fflush(stdout);

  for (;;) { 
    int c = wgetch(stdscr);

    // Exit the program on new line fed
    if (c == '\n')
      break;

    char buffer[512];
    size_t max_size = sizeof(buffer);
    if (c == ERR) {
      snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Nothing happened.");
    }
    else if (c == KEY_MOUSE) {
      MEVENT event;
      if (getmouse(&event) == OK) {
        snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Mouse at row=%d, column=%d bstate=0x%08lx",
                 event.y, event.x, event.bstate);
      }
      else {
        snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Got bad mouse event.");
      }
    }
    else {
      snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Pressed key %d (%s)", c, keyname(c));      
    }

    move(0, 0);
    insertln();
    addstr(buffer);
    clrtoeol();
    move(0, 0);
  }

  printf("\033[?1003l\n"); // Disable mouse movement events, as l = low

  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

When I put that into a file and compile it (`gcc -o test test.c -lncurses`), in xterm, mouse movements are reported without a button press. In gnome-terminal and Konsole, the movement events are only reported if a button on my mouse is pressed!

I would usually say it's just a compatibility/ standards thing BUT when I execute:

`printf '\033[?1003h'` on gnome-terminal or konsole, I can see all the mouse movements reported without any buttons pressed!

So what's going on here? How do I persuade gnome-terminal and konsole to behave like xterm? Or even to behave like themselves when they are in bash mode?

EDIT: Additional clues:

It appears this code works on all terminals if I scroll my mouse wheel. It's more than likely that this is what happened when I originally tested in xterm, as even xterm requires either a button pressed or the mouse to be scrolled for this to work.

Therefore: my question becomes why does the terminal only report mouse movement after the `bstate` has been modified in some way, even when the terminal reports escape sequences in bash mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ncurses not capturing mouse movements but terminal is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605466/ncurses-not-capturing-mouse-movements-but-terminal-is)

Comment: @Thomas Dickey That's my own question; the problem is similar, but not the same. The escape sequence is flushed with a newline here, and even if you explicitly add a fflush, the issue persists

Comment: There's no `fflush` after the `printf` in the example.  ncurses and the printf use separate buffers for writing to the standard output.

Comment: @ThomasDickey `printf` is buffered internally until newline is reached. The newline in this code implicitly flushes the buffer, and as I said, even if an explicit `fflush` is added to the example code, the issue persists.

Comment: Take a look at it using strace.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I think I've got it, actually. about 80 lines in, before any reading or polling operations, I see `write(1, "\33?1003h\n", 9) = 9`

Comment: fwiw, it works properly if you use the ncurses terminal description [xterm-1003](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-1003) (and since mixing printf's with ncurses is out of scope for bug-reports, not much that I can suggest).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Fair enough, I appreciate the help. I'm a fan of your work. Do you mind telling me how I'd apply that terminal description?

Comment: Using just the text in that, and [xterm+sm+1003](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_sm_1003) (just above that in the terminal database), compile the file using infocmp and set `TERM` to `xterm-1003`.